# Not getting current location in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation, ionic3

I'm trying to display the current location but it only returns latitude and longitude with an empty value without no errors in the console. i dont know exacly what did i forgot . it seems everything is okay .

Here is my code :

## driver.ts:

```
`import ....
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-driver',
  templateUrl: 'driver.html',
})
export class DriverPage {
  driver ={
    name :'****',
    lastName: '*****',
    email : '*****@gmail.com',
  };
place ={
  lat :0,
  lang :0 ,
} ;
 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
     public navParams: NavParams,
     private geo :Geolocation
  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DriverPage');
  }
  
  driverPosition (){
this.geo.getCurrentPosition().then(pos=>{
this.place.lat=pos.coords.latitude;
this.place.lang=pos.coords.longitude;
}).catch(err=>
  console.log('Error getting location', err)
)}
 

}
```

`

## driver.html:

```
<ion-header >
   driver
</ion-header>
<ion-content >
<ion-item >
    <p>latitude: <strong>{{place.lat}}</strong> </p>
    <p>langitude : <strong>{{place.lang}}</strong> </p>
</ion-item>
  </ion-content>
```

I also added it to *providers in app.module.ts*.

Answer (score 0):

You're not even calling your method **driverPosition**!

Put it in ngOnInit.

```
  ngOnInit (){
     this.driverPosition();
}
```

Comment: Wow.That's exactly the problem .Thanks alot ! whe i saw your answer i remembered  another way by : adding  it to the constructor .Thanks alot again

Comment: You're welcome! Though I don't recommend putting it in the constructor.

Comment: Thank alot ! i will take your advice .